"firebase deploy --only functions" failing, after an update
I am having an issue on a firebase project of mine.
I recenty updated firebase running:
% npm install -g firebase-tools

So going from:
% firebase --version              
13.10.1

to:
% firebase --version              
13.11.2

Then a bit later, when running for the first time (after the update):
% firebase deploy --only functions

I end up with this error at the end:
.....
There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a
Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine
and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.
⚠  functions: Upload Error: HTTP Error: 403, Write access
to project 'myproject-8d760' was denied: please check billing account
associated and retry
I have never seen this before. Though I have run many times the command:
% firebase deploy --only functions

I wonder it has anything to do with the update I just made.
Of course I went to take a look at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine, but I don't see what to do.
Any help would be more than welcome.

Stack Overflow is not likely to resolve this issue for you, since it doesn't seem to have anything to do with your code. (Though if it think it's related to your code, you need to show a minimal complete reproducible example to work with.)  You should take this directly to Firebase by filing an issue on GitHub or contacting Firebase support directly.

You should also consider downgrading your firebase-tools to check and see if this error is strongly correlated to the version of the CLI.

@Doug. I followed your tip coming back to my old version of the CLI (13.10.1). And the problem is still there. So that was not due to my update. But I have to deal with this "Google App Engine" issue, I think I had never heard of that before. What is this all about ?
